# Using subtle in a Javascript module, from both the browser and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

NodeJS has an experimental implementation of the browser's [crypto.subtle](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#web-crypto-api).

I have written a Javascript module which runs in both the browser and the NodeJS.  It needs access to subtle.

For the moment, every function which needs to use `subtle` awaits the following function at the beginning of execution:

```
async function getSubtle() {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') { // running in NodeJS
    const crypto = await import('crypto');
    return crypto.webcrypto.subtle;
  } else { // running in a browser
    return crypto.subtle;
  }
}
```

This works, but is slow and ugly as I'm re-importing the code on every function call (in NodeJS).

My project is simple enough that I do not use a build system.  (I use express and symlink the modules I require, e.g. from `public/js/modules/foo.mjs` to `lib/foo.js`.)

Can I replace `getSubtle()` with a module-level non-async conditional import?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This works in both Node and Browser:

```
globalThis.crypto.randomUUID()
```

and

```
globalThis.crypto
```